# Odd whining sound from planes passing over

Tags: noise

I'm trying to figure out what is causing the sounds that I'm hearing from planes passing over my house. I'm located approximately 60 miles NW of ATL. The noise I hear sounds like a turbine rapidly spinning up, and then back down approximately 5 seconds after. My theory is that this is from an initial descent, relieving some resistance on the turbine blades, but can't quite find the sound anywhere else. I have never heard this sound prior to moving here to GA a year ago and I have lived near major airports near Newark, Virginia Beach, and several military bases throughout my career. I do not have a recording yet as the planes are not quite visible when this occurs and I also don't hear the approach.

Comment: Is the sound, or rather the pitch change categorically the same, or is there variation between each occurence?

Comment: See also: [What makes the swooping noise when a jet flies overhead?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27461/1696)

Comment: Is the rapid change in both pitch and loudness?

Comment: A recording would be helpful.

Comment: I believe what you are hearing is caused by the doppler effect.  https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-3/The-Doppler-Effect

Comment: There doesn't happen to be a very large wall (such as a part of a large building, or a large free-standing wall) near you does there?  I heard some strange sound effects a few days ago as GA aircraft took off and landed on a nearby runway, that were clearly due to the way the sound was bouncing off the long metal hangar wall located right next to the place where I was sitting.